# Posts to Wordpress sites via Dropbox fetch and reporting the URLs?

Tags: wordpress, dropbox, article

Sorry for the disturbing title, it's hard to describe what I want.

I have a list of about 60 wordpress websites. On each website I have a Contributor account registered (so I can not use the XML-RPC support) and I post about 1-5 articles on every website, every month.

- The articles (about 150/month) is delivered to me via Dropbox.
- I manually log into each website with a specific Username and Password
- I post the articles on websites
- I save the URL:s to each post in a list

Does anyone know if there is a program that can automate this process? Alot of copy and pasting and it is taking **hours** each month!

I heard that iMacro may be a suggestion, but I would love if the program could fetch the articles straight from Dropbox.

*Show me what you can do!*

/Liu Kang

Comment: At *Contributor* level? Hardly... Can you offer your own mini-plugin to be installed in those 60 sites? . . . I never used, but take a look at [Windows Live Writer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/48566/12615).

Comment: No plugins allowed. Windos Live was interesting, but It's not good enough to what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iMacros was definitely the answer here, I am working on a customized code at the moment and it's going really good. Running into some problems, but I usally solve them.

Got a code now that can:

- Login to a website
- Fetch article information from a .CSV
- Post the article to the website
- Save a report containing information what article that were posted and where
- Save information about if the post was successfull (or not)
- Logout, clear cookies
- GOTO next website