# Import .CSV data into Javascript and run execute if string contains data

Tags: javascript, imacros

I have a couple of iMacro-files, that is executed with a single javascript file.

Very basic, looks like this.

```
iimPlay("GoogleMacro.iim");
iimPlay("IBMMacro.iim");
iimPlay("IMDBMacro.iim");
iimPlay("AltavistaMacro.iim");
iimPlay("GametrailersMacro.iim");
iimPlay("MortalCombatMacro.iim");
iimPlay("WikipediaMacro.iim");
```

It is called *playme.js*, and works really good.

Though, I don't want to run every macro each time I launch the .js file.

I have a separate CSV-file, *urldata.csv*

```
URLINFO,URLINFO2,DATA1,DATA2
http://google.com,GOOGLE,"hello","thank you for searching" 
http://ibm.com,IBM,null,null
http://imdb.com,IMDB,null,null
http://altavista.com,ALTAVISTA,"rip","rest in peace, my friend",
http://gametrailers.com,GAMETRAILERS,null,null
http://mortalkombat.wikia.com,MORTALKOMBAT,null,null
http://wikipedia.org,WIKIPEDIA,null,null
```

The way I want it to work, in this case (the data above in *urldata.csv*), the .js file would only execute GoogleMacro.iim and AltavistaMacro.iim

The rule I am looking for: If COL3 has the value **null**, do not iimPlay, and check the next file in line.

The .JS code should **work** (I am very aware of this is just gibberish) like this:

```
#Import urldata.csv

Loop whole CSV {
ROW2, If COL3 = null --> go to ROW3
else iimPlay("GoogleMacro.iim");
ROW3, If COL3 = null --> go to ROW4
else iimPlay("IBMMacro.iim");
Etc..
}
```

I need to figure out:

- How to import/read the data from *urldata.csv* to my *playme.js*. Apparently, [jQuery is not allowed in the free version of iMacros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579587/include-jquery-into-javascript-and-use-it-in-imacros#comment18906413_13617055) and therefore I cannot use this.
- How to make a function that only use iiPlay if the value on row X is something else than null.

Please help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved!**

Changed the .csv to the following:

```
"http://google.com",GoogleMacro,"hello","thank you for searching" 
"http://ibm.com",IBMMacro,"",""
"http://imdb.com",IMDBMacro,"",""
"http://altavista.com,ALTAVISTAMacro","rip","rest in peace, my friend",
"http://gametrailers.com",GAMETRAILERSMacro,"",""
"http://mortalkombat.wikia.com",MORTALKOMBATMacro,"",""
"http://wikipedia.org",WIKIPEDIAMacro,"",""
```

And got some really good help with the .js

```
var load;
load =  "CODE:";
load +=  "SET !DATASOURCE urldata.csv" + "\n";
load +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 4" + "\n";
load +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}" + "\n";
load +=  "SET !extract {{!col2}}" + "\n";
load +=  "ADD !extract {{!col3}}" + "\n";

var siteName = "";
var siteContent = "";

//Change 4 to the number of websites
for(i=1;i<4;i++) {

  iimSet("i",i);
  // Load data
  iimPlay(load);
  siteName = iimGetLastExtract(1);

  // Check if the website has content
  siteContent = iimGetLastExtract(2);

  if(siteName != "Website" && siteContent != "") {
     iimPlay(siteName + '.iim');
  } else {
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a GET request to get the contents of your CSV file (jQuery might help with that), then use a CSV parser (maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/14991797/711902) to parse the file, then loop through each row, and call the function if it matches your expectation.

```
jQuery.get('urldata.csv', function(response) {
    var data = parseCSV(response);
    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        var col3 = data[2], url = data[0];
        if (col3 != 'null') {
            var site = getSiteFromUrl(url);
            iimPlay(site + 'Macro.iim');
        }
    }
});

function getSiteFromUrl(url) {
    var site = url.match(/\/\/(.*)\./)[1];
    return site[0].toUpperCase() + site.substr(1);
}
```

Comment: Seems to be a problem with including jQuery into .JS when using iMacros. Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579587/include-jquery-into-javascript-and-use-it-in-imacros

Could it be solved without using jQuery?